# How do I receive data in my HttpPost in C# as a custom class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How do I receive the data coming from the post (.../api/search) as a custom c# object?

Do I receive as a JSON string, deserialize it, then cast to my object? How do I do that?

Or do I receive it immediately as a SearchObject? How would I do that?

Right now my POST request is returning a blank object "{}".

```
namespace Safety.Api
        {
            [RoutePrefix("api")]
            public class SearchController : ApiController
            {
                [Route("search")]
                [HttpPost]
                public string TestSearch([FromBody] SearchObject mystring)
                {
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mystring);
                }

            }
        }
```

This is my custom class:

```
public class SearchObject
{
    string distributionType,
        distributionTemplate,
        productLine,
        studyOfOccurrence,
        countryOfOccurrence;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the values on your class as properties e.g.:

```
public class SearchObject
{
    public string DistributionType { get; set; }
    public string DistributionTemplate { get; set; }
    public string ProductLine { get; set; }
    public string StudyOfOccurrence { get; set; }
    public string CountryOfOccurrence { get; set; }
}
```

The middleware in ASP.NET will automatically convert the object in the body to your class (if it can). It looks for a `set` method on each class member to do this. As your class only had variables then the middleware was unable to find a matching property and, as you saw, it did not populate the object.

The method should now return the correct values as a serialized JSON object.

Comment: The `public` is what i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WebApi will automatically deserialize JSON to the parameter type of the action. You can also return complex objects and WebApi will serialize these to JSON before they are sent.

So if your action looks like this

```cs
[Route("search")]
[HttpPost]
public SearchObject TestSearch([FromBody] SearchObject yourSearchObject)
{
    return yourSearchObject;
}
```

And you perform a javascript fetch request like this

```js
fetch('/api/search', {
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        distributionType: 'some type',
        distributionTemplate: 'a template',
        productLine: 'the product line',
        studyOfOccurence: 'the study',
        countyOfOccurence: 'a country'
    }),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

The `console.log(data)` statement should output

```json
{
    distributionType: 'some type',
    distributionTemplate: 'a template',
    productLine: 'the product line',
    studyOfOccurence: 'the study',
    countyOfOccurence: 'a country'
}
```

I've had trouble in the past where WebApi will try to return XML instead of JSON, or it will try to parse the data from the request as XML instead of JSON. By setting the content type header to application/json, you're telling WebApi to parse the data as JSON. You can allso set the 'accepts' header to application/json if you find that the action is returning the data as XML